# Javascript component does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, components, internet-explorer-9

There is a component that I have been using since IE7 and had never had problems with it.

Now that IE9 came out, there is a specific issue that users are struggling with.

It's a combobox, and the problem is that when I select the item, IE9 does not recognize that an item has been selected. The problem will only go away if the user turns compability mode on.

So.. question...

Is there a code parser, or code checker, or something... so that I can identify which js functions, in the component code, are no longer available in IE9? Or... does anyone have a good advice of what should I do, or how can I detect the problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you tried to change document type, and make sure that <!doctype is first line in your response.

Comment: You can start by pressing f12, open the console, and see if it shows any error; if you're lucky, you'll know the unsupported function

Comment: I'll make sure that <!doctype is there, and I will give F12 + console a try.

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to call: document.appendChild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the developer tools, and check the console to see which lines throw an error. To open the developer tools, just press F12 OR go to Tools > Developer tools. Next, press console in the tabbar.

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to call: document.appendChild

Comment: I know IE doesn't allow appendChild in some conditions, but I can't help you with this little info..