# anonymousIdentification to go away when browser closes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, formsauthentication

I am trying to use aspx anonymousIdentification, but I ran into a problem.

How can I make the cookie go away, disappear, die, when the browser is closed?

I know I can manually, with some code, get rid of it (user clicks on log off, or on a browser close event), but that is not suficient.

Any help would be appreciated. This is the tag in the web.config file:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieName=".Blahblah" cookieTimeout="99999" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" domain=".domain.com" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close) post on how to clear cookies upon closing a browser window.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it did not solve my problem. Changing the Expires property of the Cookie caused the cookie to stop working. I also tried changing the value on CookieTimeout to 0, but then the application crashed because that value is required.

Comment: Can you explain why it is insufficient to remove the cookie when the browser is closed?

Comment: Additionally, you should accept ThomasM's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9132219/19308) to your [Javascript question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9132048/19308).

Comment: Well... My concern is: what would happen if the user's browser crashes and they have to kill the process (iexplore.exe). If that happens, I am unable to call any events or the user will not be able to click on a log off button.

Comment: Answer accepted. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Now... also... I am not finding a way to delete the cookie. I tried:HttpCookie aCookie;
string cookieName;
int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
    cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
    aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
}

Comment: Found what I needed to delete the cookies, I had to set the domain value for a fake cookie to overwrite it. But I still can't find a way to delete it when the browser is closed...